# Flask static_folder hosted on S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, jinja2

I am trying to reroute all of my /static content to host on Amazon S3.  My first thought was to use global config['path'] throughout my jinja templates, but this won't work for external css and js files, plus it is kind of messy.  I found the static_folder and static_url_path released in 0.7 and this seems like what I want.  However, when I go to http://localhost:8000/static/img/abc.jpg  it does not locate the files on S3.  Am I using this feature right or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I recently developed a Flask extension to deal with just this situation. It's called [Flask-S3](https://github.com/e-dard/flask-s3), and you can read the documentation for it [here](http://flask-s3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

As an example, here is how you would integrate it into your Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_s3 import FlaskS3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'mybucketname'
s3 = FlaskS3(app)
```

You can use the extension to upload your assets to your chosen bucket:

```
>>> from my_application import app
>>> from flask_s3 import create_all
>>> create_all(app)
```

Flask-S3 is blueprint aware, and will upload all assets associated with any *registered* blueprints.

Answer (score 7):

I wish the `flask.Flask` constructor's `static_url_path` argument would accept a full URI, but it screams about the path needing a leading slash when you try that. If it accepted it, you could just use `url_for` after setting `static_url_path='http://my_s3_bucket.aws.amazon.com/'` or so.

Another possible solution is to use a context processor. I believe this is the cleanest solution, but I don't have much experience with flask. It sure *looks* clean. Using a context processor, I pull the URL from the environment (I'm using heroku so it's wicked easy to set). Then the context processor makes the static_url variable available in my templates.

**In app.py:**

```
# Environment has STATIC_URL='http://my_s3_bucket.aws.amazon.com/'
@app.context_processor
def inject_static_url():
    """
    Inject the variable 'static_url' into the templates. Grab it from
    the environment variable STATIC_URL, or use the default.

    Template variable will always have a trailing slash.

    """
    static_url = os.environ.get('STATIC_URL', app.static_url_path)
    if not static_url.endswith('/'):
        static_url += '/'
    return dict(
        static_url=static_url
    )
```

**In the template:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ static_url }}css/main.css" />
```

**The result**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://my_s3_bucket.aws.amazon.com/css/main.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but here's how I get around this issue.

- Import Flask's `url_for` method under a different name (e.g., `flask_url_for`)
- Create your own *custom* `url_for` method, which calls `flask_url_for` and then uses string replacement to add in your S3 bucket url.

I like this strategy because it's simple and intuitive to use, and the interface is exactly like the original `url_for` method.

```
from flask import url_for as flask_url_for
from flask import current_app

PRODUCTION_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/MY-BUCKET-NAME'

def url_for(path, **kwargs):
    url = flask_url_for(path, **kwargs)
    if url.startswith("/static") and not current_app.debug:
        url = url.replace("/static", "", 1)
        return PRODUCTION_URL + url
    return url
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to accomplish is to be able to write

`{{ url_for(app.static, file='img/abc.jpg', _external=True) }}`

and have that resolve to a url in s3?

i believe that static_folder and static_url_path are setup so that if you call

`app = Application('app', static_folder='foo', static_url_path='bar')`

then going to

the above url_for would output

`http://localhost:8000/bar/img/abc.jpg` and it would look for `static/img/abc.jpg` in the filesystem.

i think what you want to do is potentially write a custom filter that would translate your path to an s3 url so that you could make a call something like

`{{ 'img/abc.jpg'|s3_static_url }}`

there's some documentation on that here:  [flask custom filters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#registering-filters)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Amazon S3 public file URL instead of `http://localhost:8000/static/img/abc.jpg`. If its just a few files, maybe hardcode them in your template with the full URL or if you are going to have a local version for testing and use S3 on production site (like we do) then you can try the following method.

Define a new variable probably called `STATIC_ROOT` in the top of your base template (which other templates inherit), and use that as the file path prefix.

For example:

```
{% if app.debug %}
    {% set  STATIC_ROOT = url_for('static', filename='') %}
{% else %}
    {% set STATIC_ROOT = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/' }
{% endif %}
```

This will give you the default path when you might be testing your application locally, and the public S3 url when in production (based on debug flag).

Using it:

`<script src="{{ STATIC_ROOT }}js/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: Ugly, no need. Just use a context processor to set the variable.